# Ubuntu corrupted log files

Tags: 12.04, apache2, log, chmod, openssh

It seems that all my log folders located in /var/log are turning into files.

For example, if I try to tail /var/log/apache2.log it will say "no such file or directory"

I can see it in the file structure but can't do a single thing with it. I am experiencing some major problems overall with my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Any ideas what this could be?

**UPDATE:**

Here's an error when I try to restart apache:

```
root@ww2:~# sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting(20)Not a directory: apache2: could not open error log file /var/log/apache2/error.log.                                                  
Unable to open logs
```

Also output requested (ls -la /var/log):

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 mysql
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 mysql.err
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 mysql.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 mysql.log.5.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 mysql.log.6.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 mysql.log.7.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 mysql.log.8.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 news
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 nginx
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 php5-fpm.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 plesk-install
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 plesk-roundcube
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 psa-horde
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 railgun
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 rkhunter.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 rkhunter.log.old
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 sa-update.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 sw-cp-server
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 sw-cp-server_back
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 sw-cp-server_backup
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 syslog
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 syslog.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 syslog.7.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 udev
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 ufw.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 upstart
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 wdcollect.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  768 Jan  7 17:24 wtmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan  7 17:05 wtmp.1
```

Output of (ls -la /var/log/apache2)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  7 17:05 /var/log/apache2
```

Output of mount:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

Doing a /forcefsck I get these at startup:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/26uz62ocsilzz68/Screenshot%202014-01-07%2018.23.21.jpg
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1qb26n6hp9ljh4u/Screenshot%202014-01-07%2018.23.04.png

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I know - it still says no such file or directory.

Comment: Nope - it shows apache2 in /var/log as a 0 byte "document" with no extension. All of my log files/folders have been turned into this ghost form

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I know - tail won't open the error log. It says it doesn't exist. If I touch it, it says "not a directory"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen done.

Comment: I did sudo -s to get to root. is that what you are asking? @bodhi.zazen

Comment: Sorry - updated answer with output @bodhi.zazen

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Come to think of it, this install is on a VM, so SSH doesn't show all the startup errors, but I do remember an OSError on startup. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Should i sudo touch /forcefsck?

Comment: yes, and see if you can catch the start up errors. What virtualization ? vbox/ kvm?

Comment: just standard hyperv @bodhi.zazen

Comment: @bodhi.zazen updated with startup errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

then do:

```
sudo bleachbit
```

clean up the system.

Then do the following:

```
sudo apt-get -f update
sudo apt-get -f upgrade
```

and if you still have problems:

```
sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

You are not an enterprise so you shouldn't be worrying about having LTS versions but a stable version that satisfies your needs and solves your problems. You could also update to Ubuntu 13.10.

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo update-manager -d
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: I would not use bleachbit indiscriminately, nothing wrong with apt, so apt-get -f will not do much, upgrade is unlike to solve anything either as the problem is with the log files, and last, "dist-upgrade" does not do what you think it does ;)

Comment: This didn't fix my ghost log issues :(

Comment: Hoped it helped because it normally does remove logs, try the update if you wish its the only alternative I know I can give you at the moment, an update is always good, you can also remove the log under sudo or open it with gedit.

Comment: @Brask updated with startup errors and screen shots